# Error: Undefined on get object attribute in Vue (Nuxt)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a 'region' object, and it is displayed normally, with all the attributes, but when I need to access some of its attributes, it says that it is 'undefined'.

`const region = { "id": 7, "name": "Paraiba", "slug": "paraiba", "created_at": "2022-09-14T23:44:10.000000Z", "updated_at": "2022-09-14T23:44:10.000000Z" }`

If I display {{ region }} it displays complete: { "id": 7, "name": "Paraíba", "slug": "paraiba", "created_at": "2022-09-14T23:44:10.000000Z ", "updated_at": "2022-09-14T23:44:10.000000Z" }

However, if I print {{ region.name }} it returns undefined.

Comment: Can you post your entire component? And are you on Vue2 or Vue3?

Answer (score 0):

As the call is via API, it is not loaded after, but before, but the property did not exist. Solved!

{{ region?.name }}